# How to force signature part to remain on the same page?

Tags: newlfm

I am trying to write a one-page cover letter by using `newlfm` package. When I write everything that I want to write, the signature part "Sincerely, Name"  shows up in the next page. I tried to decrease font size as a practical solution but I still have the same problem. Another possible solution is to remove `\addfrom` but then this part shows my address and stuff.I have provided my MWE but this would not help because you won't see my problem. One way to see my problem is to increase bla bla to the point where signature leans out of first page. I know this is vague but any idea to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tgbonum}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\newlfmP{sigsize=0pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{John John}
\today\\[1ex]
XYZ Road\\
ABC Block\\
123 Apartment\\
T Land
}
\phonefrom{1213}
\emailfrom{xyz@abc} 

\addrto{X Committee\\
Y Road\\
P Land
}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Yours Faithfully,}
\begin{document}

\begin{newlfm}

Bla bla

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You will need to provide some sample version of code that demonstrates the problem, if you want to raise your odds of receiving a useful solution.

Comment: You can increase the available space on a page with the `geometry` package, see, e.g., https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins. But maybe it is better to reduce the text itself, being concise and to the point is generally appreciated - and often needed in LaTeX when you are dealing with page limits for scientific conferences and journals.

Comment: I had the same problem. My solution was to add the line `\footermarginsize{10pt}` just below the `\documentclass` line. The problem is that the default footer margin size is 72pt which is too big. Hence, the signature ends up on the next page even though it seems that there's enough space on the first page. Reducing the footer margin size fixes it. Just don't make it too small or you'll get an error.