# How to use \footermarginsize{} in Overleaf?

Tags: header-footer, footer

I am writing a letter and want to keep signature on the same page. In [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305533/how-to-force-signature-part-to-remain-on-the-same-page) it is suggested to add `\footermarginsize{10pt}` line. However it works badly - Overleaf says that it is `undefined control sequence` and it leaves the line "10pt" above the address but actually it does the trick and signature remains on the same page. How can I achieve correct work of that function?

Using `\usepackage[scale=0.75, footskip = 10pt, includefoot]{geometry}` does not help to keep signature on the page.

Comment: Overleaf just uses a standard latex so commands are defined or not depending which cpackages you have used not depending on you using overleaf.  `\footermarginsize` is not a standard command that I recognise but whatever documentation you saw that suggested it will have told you how to define it.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) `\footermarginsize` is not a standard macro so unless your document setup is 100% like the one in the links question, then that macro is obviously not available. Thus (3) please always provide a minimal, self contained example so we can have an idea as to what exactly you are doing.

Comment: It seems newlfm has some issues, see alternatives or workarounds here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583798/newlfm-expect-new-fancyhdr-sty-but-its-the-newest/583923#583923